# How to reference systemd service unit by name in Nixos configuration?

Tags: nix, nixos

I have a `services.nix` file defined which I reference/import in a Nixos config.

Which looks something like:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

let
...
in
rec {
  services.postgresql = ...;

  tgsendPostgres = import ./tgsend.nix { 
    pkgs = pkgs;
    lll = "postgresql"; # <------ this value here
  }; 
}
```

Instead of having the `postgresql` value as a string, I'd like to instead have it declaratively / statically refer to `service.postgresql`, for the purpose of catching typos at build time.

How can I get the `postgresql` value out of a service definition? I thought it would just be an attribute value like `service.postgresql.name` but instead it seems to just be stored within the attribute set's key within `service`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the service name from the `systemd.services.<name>` attribute set alone, but you can use an [assertion](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/constructs.html#assertions) where you use the name to ensure that the service exists.

I recommend refactoring `tgsend.nix` into a proper NixOS module with options, so that you can access things like `config`. Using `import` in the way that you do is quite uncommon. Remember that NixOS modules can work in layers: It's perfectly fine to have a module that configures another in a more opinionated way.

```hs
{ config, lib, ... }:

let
  cfg = config.#...
in
{
  options./*...*/ = {
    lll = lib.mkOption {
      type = with lib.types; str;
      # ...
    };
  };

  config = assert config.systemd.services ? cfg.lll; {};
}
```

Comment: Where do I specify the <name> in this example?